# node:console test is producing TypeError: Console is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, api, console

I already know how to use the global implementation on console, but I would like to use the  Node.js Console module. The code below is copied from the tutorial. (https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v19/console/)

```
import Console from 'node:console'; //when using modules
or
const { Console } = require('node:console'); //when using straight js


const output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
// Custom simple logger
const logger = new Console({ stdout: output, stderr: errorOutput });
// use it like console
const count = 5;
logger.log('count: %d', count);
// In stdout.log: count 5
```

but I am getting the following error

```
const logger = new Console({ stdout: output, stderr: errorOutput });
               ^

TypeError: Console is not a constructor
```

I am using Node.js v19.8.1
I have tried both modules and straight js. I can make the global implementation of console work, but not this. What am I doing wrong?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
console.log(Console)
```

I was able to find the available methods

```
Object [console] {
  log: [Function: log],
  warn: [Function: warn],
  dir: [Function: dir],
  time: [Function: time],
  timeEnd: [Function: timeEnd],
  timeLog: [Function: timeLog],
  trace: [Function: trace],
  assert: [Function: assert],
  clear: [Function: clear],
  count: [Function: count],
  countReset: [Function: countReset],
  group: [Function: group],
  groupEnd: [Function: groupEnd],
  table: [Function: table],
  debug: [Function: debug],
  info: [Function: info],
  dirxml: [Function: dirxml],
  error: [Function: error],
  groupCollapsed: [Function: groupCollapsed],
  Console: [Function: Console],
  profile: [Function: profile],
  profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
  timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
  context: [Function: context]
}
```

so this works

```
// use it like console
const count = 5;
Console.log('count: %d', count);
// In stdout.log: count 5
```